# Add rectangle over row of heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to add rectangle box (i.e. `graphics::rect`) around a row of a `heatmap` function call like this:

```
stats::heatmap(matrix(data = rnorm(25),nrow = 5,ncol = 5),Colv = NA,scale = "none")
```

In order to determine the parameters of `rect` I need to be able to automatically retrieve the xlim and ylim of the plotted heatmap (not the dendrogram on the side), but I'm not sure how to do so.. the limits don't seem to be 1:5 (for this example).

Comment: `par("usr")` reveals the user-coordinates range from 0-1 (X) and 0-1 (Y), so ... it's fractional based on the number of rows in the data passed to it. ... unfortunately, `heatmap` is not mapping from 0 to 1, so ... sorry, not there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick to knowing where to put a `rect`angle is to get to the right user coordinates. Unfortunately, `par("usr")` (my initial guess) returns `c(0, 1, 0, 1)`, not helpful. However, I found a clue as to *why* this is the case by reading [`?heatmap`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/heatmap.html) where, in the "Note"s at the end, it says

```
     ‘heatmap()’ uses layout and draws the image in the lower right
     corner of a 2x2 layout.  Consequentially, it can *not* be used in
     a multi column/row layout, i.e., when ‘par(mfrow = *)’ or ‘(mfcol
     = *)’ has been called.
```

This means we cannot decompose the user-coordinates of the subplot after the whole plot is complete. However ... in the same help page, we see

```
add.expr: expression that will be evaluated after the call to image.
          Can be used to add components to the plot.
```

I believe "call to image" means the actual matrix-color plot.

So I tried this:

```r
stats::heatmap(mtx, Colv = NA, scale = "none", add.expr = { browser(); 1; })
Browse[4]> par("usr")
[1] 0.5 5.5 0.5 5.5
```

Okay, so we need to add your `rect` to the `add.expr` call, and the coordinates are intuitive.

```r
whichrow <- 3
xs <- c(0, ncol(mtx)) + 0.5
ys <- (whichrow - 1:0) + 0.5
stats::heatmap(
  mtx, Colv = NA, scale = "none",
  add.expr = {
    rect(xs[1], ys[1], xs[2], ys[2], lwd = 3, xpd = NA)
  }
)
```

[image: base R graphics heatmap with rectangle overlaid]

Notes:

- the lower-left corner of the bottom-left is `0.5, 0.5`, so we need to offset the `xs` and `ys` accordingly
- `xpd=NA` is to stop "clipping"; without it, a portion of the left/right rectangle borders is clipped and therefore thinner; not required but consistent

---

Data

```r
set.seed(42)
mtx <- matrix(data = rnorm(25), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly for me! I hadn't even noticed the add.expr parameter but it solved the problem exactly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do this very exact same thing, and found `image` much easier to work with than `heatmap`. I dont know if there are other considerations between the two commands, but say you wanted to draw a transparent black rectangle around the fourth row:

```
image(matrix(data = rnorm(25),nrow = 5,ncol = 5), axes = FALSE)
axis(1, seq(0,1, length.out = 5), 1:5)
axis(2, seq(0,1, length.out = 5), 1:5)
p <- par("usr")
# [1] -0.125  1.125 -0.125  1.125

rect(xleft = p[1], xright = p[2], ybottom = p[3] + 0.75, ytop = p[4] - 0.25, 
     col = adjustcolor("black", alpha.f = 0.5), lwd = 2)
```

Then you just adjust to your needs. Again, I know you asked for `heatmap` specifically but others may find this useful

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Perfect for the ```image``` version of this question like you said.